# Asp.net MVC 5 form values validating before post method and calling action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have a view that having popup box with form.And what I am doing is from popup I am displaying user information and he can edit information. So here I want to apply validations and if validation fails,need to show errors on popup.

I tried but when I submit form it submitting values and if validation fails goinh to controller and executing action.
Than my view loading again and I am losing my popup.

How can i achieve this, Anyone can help me,
Thanks in advance

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("AdminUpdate", "Images", FormMethod.Post,new {id="updateform", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
           {
                <table style="margin:auto;">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <label id="myfirstname" style="color:#336699;"></label>&nbsp;
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label>Profile Picture:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/" + item.EmailId + item.Picture)" alt="profileimage" style="height:80px;width:80px;" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label>First Name:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:10px;">
                            @Html.TextBox("firstname", item.FirstName)
                        </td>



                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label>Last Name:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBox("lasttname", item.LastName)

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label>Website:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBox("website", item.Website)

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label>Email Id:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBox("emailid", item.EmailId)

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label>Mobile:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBox("mobile", item.Phone)

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label>Address:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBox("address", item.Address)

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label>New Password</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.Password("newpassword")
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label>Profile Picture:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="file" name="newpic" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding-top:10px;">
                           &nbsp;
                        </td >
                        <td style="padding-top:10px;">
                            <input type="submit" class="form-submit" style="cursor:pointer" name="updatesubmit" value="Update" />
                        </td>                            
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBox("aid", ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"], new { style = "display:none;" })
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBox("id", item.id, new { style = "display:none;" })
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
               <label style="color:red;padding-top:6px;padding-bottom:3px;">*If you didn't provide picture and password,old values will be used</label>
           }                        <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label>First Name:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBox("firstname", item.FirstName)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label>Last Name:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBox("lasttname", item.LastName)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label>Website:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBox("website", item.Website)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label>Email Id:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBox("emailid", item.EmailId)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label>Mobile:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBox("mobile", item.Phone)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label>Address:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBox("address", item.Address)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label>New Password</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.Password("newpassword")
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label>Profile Picture:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="file" name="newpic" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            &nbsp;
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBox("aid", ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"], new { style = "display:none;" })
                            @Html.TextBox("id", item.id, new { style = "display:none;" })
                            <input type="submit" class="form-submit" name="updatesubmit" value="Update" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a id="close"> close</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
           }
```

Comment: I can't be specific without seeing your code, but the "popup" needs to prevent the default action of the HTML form so that it doesn't actually submit.  Then when validation succeeds, the JavaScript code would submit the form.

Comment: Hi David,I updated my code,Could please check and help me

Comment: I don't see any JavaScript, this looks like a standard HTML form that's going to post to the server and request a new page.  There's no client-side validation here.

Comment: I used    JQuery    for validation and got solution

Comment: set the property "Required" on each control. It will then validate.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#updateform').submit(function () {
    if ($("#firstname").val() == "" || $("#lasttname").val() == "" || $("#website").val() == "" || $("#emailid").val() == "" || $("#mobile").val() == "" || $("#address").val() == "") 
    {
        $("#myfirstname").text("*Please enter details");
        return false;
    }
    else if (!($("#firstname").val().match("^([a-zA-Z]+)?$")))
    {
        $("#myfirstname").text("*Invalid first name format");
        return false;

    }
    else if (!($("#lasttname").val().match("^([a-zA-Z]+)?$")))
    {
        $("#myfirstname").text("*Invalid last name format");
        return false;

    }
    else if (!($("#website").val().match("^((https?|ftp)://|(www|ftp)\\.)[a-z0-9-]+(\\.[a-z0-9-]+)+([/?].*)?$")))
    {
        $("#myfirstname").text("*Invalid website format");
        return false;

    }
    else if (!($("#emailid").val().match("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\\.[a-z0-9-]+)$")))
    {
        $("#myfirstname").text("*Invalid emailid format");
        return false;

    }
    else if (!($("#mobile").val().match("^\\(?([7-9]{1})\\)?([0-9]{9})$")))
    {
        $("#myfirstname").text("*Invalid mobile number");
        return false;

    }
    else if (!($("#address").val().match("^([a-zA-Z]+)?$")))
    {
        $("#myfirstname").text("*Invalid address");
        return false;

    }
    else if ($("#newpassword").val()!="")
    {
        if ($("#newpassword").val().length < 6 || $("#newpassword").val().length>10)
        {
            $("#myfirstname").text("*Password lenght min 6chars and max 10chars");
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. we can do lots of stuff using jquery in MVC applictaion, however this validation will fail if JavaScript is disabled by the user. To overcome this we can use **DataAnnotations** feature of MVC5. In such case **ModelState.IsValid** will be false ; that we can handle in controller as per requirement. You can validate data in simple manner as follows:

Model

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Name")]
[StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Name can not be more than 50 characters ")]
[DisplayName("Name")]
public string name { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Date of Birth")]
[DisplayName("Date of Birth")]
[DataType(DataType.Date,ErrorMessage = "Invalid Date ")]
public DateTime dob { get; set; }
```

Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Registration(RegistrationClass obj)
    {
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       // Code if Data is valid , may be insert data to database
    }
    else 
    {
    obj = obj.getAllDropdown();
    }
    return View(obj);
}
```

*getAllDropdown* is my user defined function to populate dropdownlist.